# Does the 2’ rule apply to return ducts?

Tags: hvac

I’m installing an HVAC system and admittedly am pretty new to it. I can’t seem to find any answers online to my question.

Can you have return takeoffs close to each other on the trunk or do you need to abide by the [2’ rule](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/224004/is-there-a-minimum-for-spacing-between-take-offs-from-an-hvac-trunk-line) like you would with supply takeoffs?

Answer (score 0):

The rule would not apply. The partial vacuum in a return trunk behaves very differently from the pressurized supply trunk.